# Salvar imagem android

Tags: java, android, imagem

Sei que provavelmente existe uma resposta aqui no site para minha pergunta, mas quando pesquisei vi diversas formas e fiquei meio perdido.

Queria criar uma pasta oculta e ter algum `ImageButton` ou algo assim que possa selecionar uma imagem da galeria (não abrir a câmera e tirar uma foto na hora) e copiar (sem apagar a imagem original) para a pasta criada

Também preciso redimensionar essa imagem caso a imagem selecionada seja muito grande, nos testes que eu fiz, a imagem ficava muito grande e cobria boa parte da tela, sendo que mesmo cobrindo outras coisas, aparecia apenas parte da imagem, para tentar resolver esse problema eu coloquei um tamanho fixo no `ImageButton`, assim não cobria o resto da tela porém cortava a imagem (mostrava só um pedaço)

Pelos testes que fiz imagino que deve ser criando uma `Intent` pra abrir a galeria com retorno, nesse retorno pegar a `URI` da imagem e transformar essa `URI` em um caminho, para poder copiar para uma outra pasta, e já na pasta transformar a imagem em `bitmap`, para poder redimensionar e depois transformar o `bitmap` em `URI` para guardar o caminho no banco para depois setar usando `setImageUri()` no resto da aplicação (em `ImageView` e `ImageButton`), porém caso o usuário cancele ou, futuramente, delete o cadastro, também seria necessário deletar o arquivo de imagem movido para a pasta criada

Outra dúvida, é qual a melhor forma de pegar essa imagem? Com um `ImageView`, `ImageButton` ou o que, se tem algum padrão?

Vi várias perguntas que respondem a essa porém casa pergunta respondia uma parte e quando fui juntar não consegui, alguém pode ajudar?

Se souberem de uma pergunta que faça isso por favor passe o link

Comment: A sua pergunta é muito ampla e foca muitos assuntos. Não existe aqui uma resposta que responda a isso tudo. No entanto existem resposta que respondem, individualmente, a cada um dos assuntos. É só você querer procurar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou deixar aqui uma lista de pontos, que vão responder sua pergunta. As implementações existem exemplos nas bibliotecas. São todas bibliotecas que utilizei em um projeto, que a unica coisa diferente do seu era que eu precisava carregar e salvar a imagem redimensionada em um storage do firebase.

> Queria criar uma pasta oculta e ter algum ImageButton ou algo assim que possa selecionar uma imagem da galeria (não abrir a câmera e tirar uma foto na hora) e copiar (sem apagar a imagem original) para a pasta criada.

Cria uma pasta no internal storage da aplicação. Lembrando que esta pasta não ficaria disponível para outros apps, somente para o seu.

```
File dir = context.getDir("DiretorioLindo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();
```

> Também preciso redimensionar essa imagem caso a imagem selecionada seja muito grande

Usa a library [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor), que ela redimensiona e comprime a imagem conforme a necessidade

> Capturar a imagem do usuario

Use a library [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper), ela mostra uma UI para selecionar de onde o usuário quiser a imagem, e também da a oportunidade dele recortar a imagem e modificar ela antes de gravar.

Lembrando que todo o tratamento das permissões e novas formas de ler arquivos no Android 7+ devem ser respeitadas.

Comment: dei uma olhada na biblioteca e você usar o `setDestinationDirectoryPath()` para mandar a imagem para um diretório, mas apaga o arquivo original? Se não apaga mantém ele igual ao original ou com as mudanças? E o que seria esses métodos `.subscribeOn()`, `.observeOn()` e `.subscribe()`?

Comment: Não apaga o original, pois ele vai gravar a imagem capturada/selecionada e depois cortada nesse diretorio. o subscribeOn() é somente se usar RxJava. Mas usa os metodos tradicionais sem eles.

Comment: Obrigado ajudo muito, teria como mandar o código da sua aplicação, posteriormente farei um aplicativo parecido com esse porém cadastrando no firebase. Obrigado

Comment: Infelizmente não posso, por questões de copyright, mas se tiver alguma dúvida vai postando aqui que vamos respondendo.

Comment: Entendo, obrigado pela ajuda, demorei um pouco pra dar a recompensa pq tava sem tempo de testar o código